# Rails3, one-to-many relationship, how to check if child model's parent_id is valid when save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models which are Parent and Child. Parent has many children and Child has one parent. one-to-many relationship using has_many and belongs_to. Child has parent_id field, of course.

I'd like to check validation for Child if its parent_id is valid(means such Parent has the ID exists).

I thought **validates_associated** is for that, but didn't work in unittest.

Do I have to create own validator or are there more general methods?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a database foreign key constraint in your migration? Something like

```
    class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :pages do |t|
          t.references :upload, :null => false
          t.integer :number
          t.integer :position
          t.integer :color

          t.timestamps
        end

        execute "ALTER TABLE pages 
                 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pages_upload_id
                 FOREIGN KEY (upload_id) REFERENCES uploads(id)"
      end

      def self.down
        execute "ALTER TABLE pages DROP CONSTRAINT fk_pages_upload_id"
        drop_table :pages
      end
end
```

This may not look like a "Rails" way of doing things, but personnaly, I have the feeling databases are underused in web applications. Constraints are powerful, why not use them!

Best regards,

Philippe

Comment: I may understand your query, but it doesn't rails way I think. Could you please suggest another one?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use both `validates_associated` and `validates_presence_of` on the child model to ensure that both the foriegn_key is populated, and the the parent model exists in that table. See the note on the docs here [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated)

Comment: Still not work for my unit test :( it generates SystemStackError: stack level too deep.

Comment: Did you specify `validates_associated` on both the child and parent models? The docs I linked to mention this will cause infinite recursion. You'll have to specify it on either the child or parent, not both